# Enable users icon not working in FileVault

Tags: macos, mojave, filevault

When I go into FileVault, I am unable to click on the Enable Users... icon to add users. How do I fix this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the Preferences window for FileVault?